# How would this C struct be translated into Python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to use the structs. What would the C structs below look like when they are converted into Python?

These are the structs I have:

```
struct dataT
{
    int m;
};

struct stack
{
    int top;
    struct dataT items[STACKSIZE];
} st;
```

How would this statement be represented in Python?

```
st.items[st.top].m
```

Comment: Python doesn't have structs.

Comment: @Kevin It basically does. A `struct` is just a `class` where all the members and methods are `public` instead of `private` by default. In fact in this regard Python's classes are closer to C's `struct` than `class` since there isn't a notion of `private`

Comment: @Cyber: You're conflating the languages. In Python, all attributes and methods are public by default (although its concept of public vs private are different from C++'s). C doesn't have classes, but C++ does, and in C++ a `struct` is simply a class where all the members and methods are public by default. In C, `struct`s can't have methods because they're not classes since there's no such thing. C also doesn't have a concept of public and private.

Comment: @martineau My mistake, I meant to write C++ in my comment above. But you are correct in your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to define your `dataT` class

```
class dataT():
    def __init__(self, m=0):
        self.m = m
```

You can instantiate one like

```
d = dataT(5)
```

The `stack` behavior you can get from the `list` class already

```
>>> l = [dataT(i) for i in range(5)]
>>> l.pop().m
4
>>> l.pop().m
3
>>> l.pop().m
2
>>> l.pop().m
1
>>> l.pop().m
0
>>> l.append(dataT(3))
>>> l.pop().m
3
```

Comment: where is it mentioned that m is an integer?  How does python know wether it is is an integer or not ?

Comment: @Benjer `m` will be whatever type you assign to it. I happened to put `int` values in there, but you can put anything. Python is not a statically-typed language.

Comment: Sorry, im pretty new to pyhton, so basically the strucutre doent have a max value assigned to it, and any element can be put into it? Is there a way to only allow integers?

Comment: Yes the `list` (analogous to your `stack`) is a Python sequence. Meaning it is sortable, indexable, resizeable, sliceable, etc. In that regard it is similar to a `std::vector<T>` in `C++`, but it is also heterogeneous. The way to limit the values to `int` would be to do some kind of validation using `isinstance(m, int)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use namedtuples to construct classes that can represent your structs:

```
from collections import namedtuple
dataT = namedtuple("dataT", ['m'])
stack = namedtuple("stack", ['top', 'items'])

st = stack(0, [])
st.items.append(dataT(5))
st.items[st.top].m
```

Though you will probably find that the stack class is unnecessary as pointed out list already has this behaviour.

Comment: A possibly very significant difference between C `struct`s and Python `namedtuple`s is that the latter are immutable.

Comment: C struct's are mutable too, e.g. `st.top = 1` would update `st` in place.

Comment: Yes, C `struct`s are mutable. `namedtuple`s are not.

Comment: Ahh, misread your comment, though the list in the namedtuple is mutable.